# How to read a String an an integer from one input in the console?

Tags: java, string, console, integer, java.util.scanner

The instructions read: 
Write a program that prompts the user to input a student first name followed by a space and an integer test grade, then the user will press enter and you will prompt them again for a name and a test grade; for a total of 10 students and 10 grades. (Ex: Dawn 100 ) ;  You must check that the user enters a grade that is >= 0 and <= 100. If not, you must prompt the user with an error message and the user must input the grade again.

I can't figure out how to do this without getting a java.util.InputMismatchException error message.

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String[] students = new String[10];
  int[] grades = new int[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < students.length; )
  {
     System.out.println("Enter a student name and grade(between 0 and 100): ");

     if(input.nextInt() > 0 && input.nextInt() <= 100)
     {
        students[i] = input.next();
        grades[i] = input.nextInt();
        i++;
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("*Error* Grade value must be between 0 and 100. Please Try again");
     }   
  }
```

Comment: also, using a while loop would be more suitable for the case that the user doesn't enter the required grade. though you could do it with a for loop with a little bit of altering. Also, this -->  `if(input.nextInt() > 0 && input.nextInt() <= 100)` will require a user to enter twice which i think is not what you want there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look...

```
if(input.nextInt() > 0 && input.nextInt() <= 100)
```

You check the input for `nextInt`, twice, so you're no longer actually comparing the same value, but also, you've asked for a `String` and an `int` value, but you've not checked for the `String` first...

Assume I entered something like `500 -1`, then you're `if` statement would pass successfully, because `500` is `> 0` and `-1` is `<= 100`

And if by some miracle, that worked, you're reading another `String` and another `int` from the stream...

```
students[i] = input.next();
grades[i] = input.nextInt();
```

So, for this to work, the input would have to be something like `1 2 John 50` ... which would just be completely weird and completely void what you're trying to do.

Instead, ask for one piece of information at a time and process it, for example...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("User name: ");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Grade: ");
String gradeValue = input.nextLine();
Scanner parser = new Scanner(gradeValue);
if (parser.hasNextInt()) {
    int grade = parser.nextInt();
    if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
        // Good grade
    } else {
    System.out.println("!! " + grade + " is not a valid grade");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("!! " + gradeValue + " is not a valid integer value");
}
```

Don't keep reading from the `Scanner` when you're not expecting a value, extract the value you need and process it.  Here I've used `nextLine` to get the grade and a second `Scanner` to parse it, it's safer and avoids the oddities where the new line is left in the buffer.  It also gives you better control to process errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to do this without getting a
>   java.util.InputMismatchException error message.

The first mistake you've made is reading user input incorrectly `input.nextInt() > 0 && input.nextInt()` this is requiring the user to enter an integer value **twice** whereas what you want is name (`string`) & grade (`int`).

the solution below takes that mistake into consideration, however personally I would use a while loop, but since you're using a for loop already I have decided to incorporate with that.

full solution:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] students = new String[10];
int[] grades = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
{
      System.out.println("Enter a student name and grade(between 0 and 100): ");
      String getInput = input.nextLine();
      if(Integer.parseInt(getInput.split(" ")[1]) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(getInput.split(" ")[1]) > 100)
      {
           System.out.println("*Error* Grade value must be between 0 and 100. Please Try again");
           i--;
      }
      else {
           students[i] = getInput.split(" ")[0];
           grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(getInput.split(" ")[1]);
      }
}
```

**note** - the solution given only takes into consideration what you've mentioned within your question i.e it is expecting input as such `Ousmane 20`, `Brendon 23` , `jack 30` etc, also you can make the program a bit more robust by adding more validations if needed maybe `NumberFormatException`, [`Scanner#hasNextInt()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm) and so forth.

Comment: And if input `Wyne Rogers 50` how would that cope ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer good point, i will edit it soon, just trying to add some context. Thanks ;)

Comment: I think we can ignore the case of two names.

Comment: Modifying the for loop control variable (`i`) inside the loop makes for unreadable code. Please don’t teach the young ones (nor anyone else) such bad manners.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw We should also avoid copy/paste answers without at least providing context to why it would solve the problem and why it's a better solution and in what ways it improves upon what the OP is doing ... given that fact that's it's probably home work ;)

Comment: @OleV.V. you're correct, as I've mentioned with a comment below  the original post, personally I would have used a while loop in which case I wouldn't manipulate "i" within the for loop However, considering OP is already using a for loop, I've decided to proceed as such. but will keep the suggestion in mind for future answers.

Comment: @MadProgrammer apologise, I will keep that in mind for future answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main culprit:

```
if(input.nextInt() > 0 && input.nextInt() <= 100)
```

Your `if` condition contains two (2) calls to `input.nextInt()`, so at this point — before reading the name — your program will attempt to read two numbers from input and see if the first is greater than 0 and the second less than or equal to 100. And if it succeeded, it would not store the numbers read into any variables.

Instead you need to read the name into `students[i]` first. Then read the grade into `grades[i]`. Then check if the grade read is in the interval. I suggest you use a `while` loop so that as long as the grade is outside the interval, you print the error message and read the grade anew. If the first grade read was OK, you `while` loop won’t execute at all, so this is fine.